# Mac OS X Network Discovery

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac, firewall, ssl-vpn

Simple question, what service/ports does Mac OS X Network Discovery used. Just NetBios?

Example: Go -> Network  if connected you should see other devices on the network. Mac OS,Windows,etc.

From what I can tell its just NetBios. However, from Windows Explorer (Windows OS), I can only see Windows boxes which makes me wonder. (This is a theory NOT the ISSUE).

The issue in which is why I am trying to find out what Mac OS Network Discovery is used, is a Sonicwall UTM/Firewall issues.

One service is a SSL-VPN service. On subnets you can see the computers you normally do. No problem. The issue when connected to SSL-VPN client with NetBios enabled and IP Helper  does not show devices in Mac OS --> Go -->Network. Doing a packet capture is not showing any drop packets.

This is why I am trying to figure out if Mac OS X Network Discovery uses something other then NetBios.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

macOS primarily uses Bonjour (mDNS, DNS-SD, IETF ZeroConf) for network service advertisement and discovery. So mainly ports 5353/UDP for multicast DNS and and 53/UDP for unicast DNS-SD (of course, unicast DNS can use 53/TCP as well). It also uses SMB browsing and name resolution mechanisms (NetBIOS, WINS) for finding SMB file servers, and for advertising its own SMB file services if SMB file sharing is enabled.

Comment: so technically would you need bonjour installed to see Mac OS File share from Windows? Or like you said for file sharing it would use NetBios for file share.

Comment: @BenjaminJones You'd only need Bonjour to discover AFP file sharing from Windows, but that doesn't matter much unless you've installed an AFP client on Windows. For SMB file sharing, it would advertise via SMB's NetBIOS-based service advertising/browsing and name resolution mechanisms.